# C# NLog - How to stop replacing newlines by NLog?

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm trying to figure out how to stop NLog from replacing the Newlines in the strings I'm logging. I want the output to include all the line breaks and not place the entire output onto one line.

Can anybody help?

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="udp" xsi:type="NLogViewer" address="udp4://192.168.0.101:7071" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="udp" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Code:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger($"Test");
var dumpStr = builder.ToString();
logger.Info(dumpStr);
```

Comment: What's `builder`'s content? Do you have correct newlines using a file-target?

Comment: This is most likely related to the viewer. I'd check a file-target as Fildor suggested.

Comment: Builder is a StringBuilder with a list of strings that correctly displays on the console as a list.

Comment: The target is NLog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the output looks is controlled by the `layout`. The [`message`](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Message-Layout-Renderer) is formatted. You can tell it to output raw with a `${message:raw=true}` declaration.

The [default](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/NLogViewer-target) layout is:

`${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}`

So we would change that to:

`${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message:raw=true}`

You would add this option to your target like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="udp" 
            xsi:type="NLogViewer" 
            address="udp4://192.168.0.101:7071" 
            layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message:raw=true}"
    />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="udp" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: I'm confused that `${message:raw=true}` gives a different result than `${message}`, in this scenario `logger.Info(dumpStr)`. NLog doesn't perform any formatting when only receving the log-message without any additional parameters.